# Possible permutations from $6$ sets of the numbers $1$ to $6$

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine I have six dice and I cut off all the faces so I have $36$ tiles and I place them in a bag.

The bag now contains $6$ sixes, $6$ fives, $6$ fours, and so on.

Now I draw randomly $6$ of the tiles from the bag.

How do I calculate the number of permutations of the six numbers drawn for a six tile sample, assuming no replacement?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Are you asking how many ways there are to permute the specific random selection?  But of course, that depends on the selection.

Comment: If you are asking how many unordered selections of six tiles there are, then [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) seems the way to go.

Comment: @lulu: _permutations!_

Comment: HINT: Since you are randomly drawing 6 tiles and you have 6 of each number, the number of tiles is no longer relevant. You could have 11 of each tile and the number of permutations would still be the same.

Comment: Apologies for being unclear.  My vision on the experiment is that the 6 tile sample drawn from the 36 tiles will be one of the set {1,1,1,1,1,1} through to {6,6,6,6,6,6} with all possible permutations in between these end members. I've worked that if I rolled six dice the number of permutations for the six faces landing upwards would be (if I'm right) 6x6x6x6x6 = 46,656.  However, I then wondered about the case of having all 36 (peeled) dice faces available then picking 6 tiles from the 36 available (hence the peeling) hopefully this helps? Is it the same as rolling six dice - perhaps not?

Comment: Perhaps an example would clarify your question.  What's the answer if you randomly draw two tiles?  Is it $36$ or is it $21$?

Answer (score 2):

Because six dice were used, *every* permutation of six numbers from one to six with repetition is possible – you can have all six ones, all six twos and so on. So the number of permutations is unrestricted and is $6^6$.

Comment: This agrees with my intuition but how do I go about showing this mathematically because the permutations of six selected from 36 object 36^6? Clearly this is because there are 6 groups in the 36 but would be interested in how to formulate this problem